# Why Oracle odbc driver gives no TYPE_NAME for integers and numeric types?

Tags: oracle, odbc, oracle11g, unixodbc

I am trying to create a table dynamically with odbc and I need to get the correct type string to use in the create table statement. However it seems there is no way to get any TYPE_NAME string from the Oracle driver (oracle-instantclient11.2-odbc-11.2.0.1.0-1.x86_64).
Calling SQLGetTypeInfo(hStmt, sqlType) with the following types always returns an empty recordest:

SQL_NUMERIC, SQL_INTEGER, SQL_BIGINT

I was expecting respectively NUMERIC, NUMERIC(10,0) and NUMERIC(19,0). Or NUMBER replacing numeric as listed in http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i16209 : NUMBER(p,s)

Instead, a list of SQL_ALL_TYPES reveals no support at all for NUMBER but instead there is an undocumented (as for the aforementioned link) DECIMAL type.

Any idea of why this behaviour and how to get the correct string without having to examine the driver connection DBMS name?

PS:
    SQL_ALL_TYPES returns:
    BLOB, LONG RAW, BFILE, RAW, CLOB, LONG, CHAR, DECIMAL, BINARY_FLOAT,
    BINARY_DOUBLE, DOUBLE PRECISION, DATE, VARCHAR2,  NCHAR,  NVARCHAR2, NCLOB

Comment: Did you try SQL_ALL_TYPES and see what it supports?

Comment: There seem to be no support for NUMBER types at all according to SQL_ALL_TYPES output (I've edited it above)

Comment: Try passing SQL_DECIMAL to SQLGetTypeInfo.  See [the ODBC docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms713607(v=vs.85)), specifically Appendix D.  Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle stores the numeric data types as follows

NUMERIC : SQL_DECIMAL=3 size 38,0
NUMERIC(10,0) : SQL_DECIMAL=3 size 10, 0
NUMERIC(19,0) : SQL_DECIMAL=3 size 19, 0

The last digit is the scale so for exmaple :-

NUMERIC(12,3) : SQL_DECIMAL=3 size 12, 3

Commercial drivers such as [Easysoft](http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc_oracle_driver/index.html) do support the require data types in ODBC :-

```
Full Connect(Default)

Env. Attr. SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION set to SQL_OV_ODBC3

Successfully connected to DSN 'ESOracle32'.
SQLGetTypeInfo:
                In:             StatementHandle = 0x00DD7C58, DataType = SQL_INTEGER=4
                Return: SQL_SUCCESS=0

Get Data All:
"TYPE_NAME", "DATA_TYPE", "COLUMN_SIZE", "LITERAL_PREFIX", "LITERAL_SUFFIX", "CREATE_PARAMS", "NULLABLE", "CASE_SENSITIVE", "SEARCHABLE", "UNSIGNED_ATTRIBUTE", "FIXED_PREC_SCALE", "AUTO_UNIQUE_VALUE", "LOCAL_TYPE_NAME", "MINIMUM_SCALE", "MAXIMUM_SCALE", "SQL_DATA_TYPE", "SQL_DATETIME_SUB", "NUM_PREC_RADIX", "INTERVAL_PRECISION"
"INTEGER", 4, 9, <Null>, <Null>, <Null>, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, "NUMBER(9)", <Null>, <Null>, 6, <Null>, 10, <Null>
1 row fetched from 19 columns.

SQLGetTypeInfo:
                In:             StatementHandle = 0x00DD7C58, DataType = SQL_NUMERIC=2
                Return: SQL_SUCCESS=0

Get Data All:
"TYPE_NAME", "DATA_TYPE", "COLUMN_SIZE", "LITERAL_PREFIX", "LITERAL_SUFFIX", "CREATE_PARAMS", "NULLABLE", "CASE_SENSITIVE", "SEARCHABLE", "UNSIGNED_ATTRIBUTE", "FIXED_PREC_SCALE", "AUTO_UNIQUE_VALUE", "LOCAL_TYPE_NAME", "MINIMUM_SCALE", "MAXIMUM_SCALE", "SQL_DATA_TYPE", "SQL_DATETIME_SUB", "NUM_PREC_RADIX", "INTERVAL_PRECISION"
"NUMBER", 2, 38, <Null>, <Null>, "precision,scale", 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, "NUMBER", <Null>, <Null>, 2, <Null>, 10, <Null>
1 row fetched from 19 columns.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my question was about ODBC drivers and how to get that response directly from the Oracle driver, querying for standard odbc enums

Comment: You can't make an ODBC call to get a NUMERIC type back because the Oracle driver does not recognise the NUMERIC type through ODBC. The way I converted the output was to create a table with a numeric column then did a SQLDescribeCol on the column.

Comment: Letting alone the SQL_NUMERIC, even the SQL_INTEGER is not recognized which, if omitted purposely, looks to me as a huge interoperability hole in Oracle drivers. Meanwhile I've hardcoded them into my "getTypeName" function discriminating upon DBMS name by the driver but it is far from an ideal solution.